# Generate a simple array of username using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

My Database

```
id  username
1   xxx
2   bbb
3   vvv
4   bbbbbb
```

i need output as

```
array('xxx','bbb','vvv','bbbbb');
```

Using PDO i need to fetch username from db & make that to array, is to for checking username exists

Comment: You don't want to fetch all usernames and then check if the username exists or not. Instead, use your database functions to validate. E.g: `SELECT username FROM table WHERE LOWER(username) = LOWER(variable)`

Comment: @Daniel yes but, in this scenario i need to generate a array of usernames. im using some ajax call for dynamic username checking

Comment: I still think you should reconsider. Fetching a bunch of usernames is not practical in the terms of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only checking if a username exist, it would be optimal to modify your query to do just that, instead of returning excess data:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1");
$query->execute(array($username_to_test));

if ($query->rowCount() == 1)
{
    // user exists in table
}
```

If you do happen to need an array of usernames, do something like the following:

```
$usernames = array();
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT `username` FROM `users`");
while(($row = $query->fetchObject()) != null)
    $usernames[] = $row->username;
```

Comment: yes, but i need a array like. array('xxx','bbb','vvv','bbbbb');

Comment: this given output.....Array ( [0] => xxx [1] => vvvv[2] => bbbb[3] => cccc[4] => aaaa [5] => mmmmm)

Comment: i need without key in the array

Comment: Not trying to be an ass here, but no-one said it was MySQL. I wouldn't recommend the backticks. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$pass);
$pdos = $pdo->prepare('select username from mytablename');
$pdos ->execute();
$results = array();
while ($row = $pdos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $results[] = $row['username'];
}
var_dump($results);
```

Set Your database $dsn, $user and $pass before [according to doc](https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php).

Comment: this given output.....Array ( [0] => xxx [1] => vvvv[2] => bbbb[3] => cccc[4] => aaaa [5] => mmmmm)

Comment: i need with out key . i.e array('xxx','bbb','vvv','bbbbb');

Comment: Hey ramya, you have big lack of php API knowleges. Array([0] => 'asd', [1] => 'aa') is the same which will produce array('asd', 'aa'). The "0" and "1" are the default array keys which will be generated by your array('asd', 'aa') construct. Check this out before: http://cz2.php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you've asked:

```
$query = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT username from users");
if ($query -> execute()){
    $user_array = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Tim Cooper's answer is probably a better solution though.